# Pandas: Counting unique values in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

We have a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
> df.ix[:2,:10]
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
0   NaN NaN NaN NaN  6   5  NaN NaN  4  NaN  5
1   NaN NaN NaN NaN  8  NaN NaN  7  NaN NaN  5
2   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  1  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

We simply want the counts of all unique values in the DataFrame. A simple solution is:

```
df.stack().value_counts()
```

However:
1. It looks like `stack` returns a copy, not a view, which is memory prohibitive in this case. Is this correct?
2. I want to group the DataFrame by rows, and then get the different histograms for each grouping. If we ignore the memory issues with `stack` and use it for now, how does one do the grouping correctly?

```
d = pd.DataFrame([[nan, 1, nan, 2, 3],
              [nan, 1, 1, 1, 3],
              [nan, 1, nan, 2, 3],
              [nan,2,2,2, 3]])

len(d.stack()) #14
d.stack().groupby(arange(4))
AssertionError: Grouper and axis must be same length
```

The stacked DataFrame has a MultiIndex, with a length of some number less than `n_rows*n_columns`, because the `nan`s are removed.

```
0  1    1
   3    2
   4    3
1  0    1
   1    1
   2    1
   3    1
   4    3
    ....
```

This means we don't easily know how to build our grouping. It would be much better to just operate on the first level, but then I'm stuck on how to then apply the grouping I actually want.

```
d.stack().groupby(level=0).groupby(list('aabb'))
KeyError: 'a'
```

Edit: A solution, which doesn't use stacking:

```
f = lambda x: pd.value_counts(x.values.ravel())
d.groupby(list('aabb')).apply(f)
a  1    4
   3    2
   2    1
b  2    4
   3    2
   1    1
dtype: int64
```

Looks clunky, though. If there's a better option I'm happy to hear it.

Edit: Dan's comment revealed I had a typo, though correcting that still doesn't get us to the finish line.

Comment: ``df.stack().groupby(list('aaaabbbb')).value_counts()`` works for me.

Comment: @DanAllan Hmmm the value_counts shortcut has been turned off in 0.13+ (thought it was whitelisted, but guess not...)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are doing a row/column-wise operation so can use `apply`:

```
In [11]: d.apply(pd.Series.value_counts, axis=1).fillna(0)
Out[11]: 
   1  2  3
0  1  1  1
1  4  0  1
2  1  1  1
3  0  4  1
```

*Note: There is a `value_counts` DataFrame method in the works for 0.14... which will make this more efficient and more concise.*

It's worth noting that the pandas `value_counts` function also works on a numpy array, so you can pass it the values of the DataFrame (as a 1-d array **view** using [`np.ravel`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html)):

```
In [21]: pd.value_counts(d.values.ravel())
Out[21]: 
2    6
1    6
3    4
dtype: int64
```

Also, you were pretty close to getting this correct, but you'd need to stack and unstack:

```
In [22]: d.stack().groupby(level=0).apply(pd.Series.value_counts).unstack().fillna(0)
Out[22]: 
   1  2  3
0  1  1  1
1  4  0  1
2  1  1  1
3  0  4  1
```

This error seems somewhat self explanatory (4 != 16):

```
len(d.stack()) #16
d.stack().groupby(arange(4))
AssertionError: Grouper and axis must be same length
```

perhaps you wanted to pass:

```
In [23]: np.repeat(np.arange(4), 4)
Out[23]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3])
```

Comment: Thanks, Andy. This gets close, but the grouping still isn't quite right. See the example I'm about to put into the original question. Also, does stack return a copy instead of a view?

Comment: The issue is the nans make the number of rows variable, so we can't readily know ahead of time how to construct an appropriate grouper for `d.stack()`. It would be better to just operate without the `stack`, as you've done; I just don't see a way to get the appropriate grouping in there.

Comment: @jeffalstott you groupby the level, stack is a copy. I'm confused what the final result is that you actually want....

Comment: Got a solution. Happy to hear of a better way of doing it. I will accept your answer in the meantime.

Answer (score 1):

Not enough rep to comment, but Andy's answer:

```
pd.value_counts(d.values.ravel())
```

is what I have used personally, and seems to me to be by far the most versatile and easily-readable solution. Another advantage is that it is easy to use a subset of the columns:

```
pd.value_counts(d[[1,3,4,6,7]].values.ravel())
```

or

```
pd.value_counts(d[["col_title1","col_title2"]].values.ravel())
```

Is there any disadvantage to this approach, or any particular reason you want to use stack and groupby?