# Pandas count results per unique server

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, dataframe

I am very new to both pandas and python. I did find this

[Pandas Count Unique Occurances by Month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23765397/pandas-count-unique-occurances-by-month)

on stackoverflow that is similar to my question, but I can't seem to manipulate the answer to address my problem so here goes:

I have a list of servers, and each server has a number of patches that apply to that server. The excel looks a bit like this:

```
Server Name - Missing Patch
Server 1 ---- file
Server 1 ---- reg
Server 1 ---- file
Server 2 ---- reg
Server 2 ---- file
Server 2 ---- file
Server 2 ---- file
Server 3 ---- reg
Server 3 ---- reg
Server 3 ---- file
Server 3 ---- reg
Server 3 ---- unicorns
```

I would like to make a dataframe that has one column of unique servers and one column counting how many missing patches there are for each server. It should look like this:

```
Server Name - Missing Patch Count
Server 1 ---- 3
Server 2 ---- 4
Server 3 ---- 5
```

I can't seem to make nunique work, and value_counts returns a series, which isn't quite what I want. I managed to get `df.drop_duplicates('Server Name')` to work to only display unique instances of server names, but I can't get it to sort the column by that data.

I realise there have been a lot of similar questions on here, but I am new to pandas and can't seem to apply the right syntax to my problem using the documentation - can anyone help?

Comment: Arrgh - 'Server Name' is a column that has the server names in it, and  'Missing Patch' and 'Missing Patch Count' are also columns - I couldn't upload a picture coz I'm new to the forum and my html sucks, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) 'Server Name', call [`count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count) and then [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html#pandas.Series.reset_index) to restore the server name column:

```
In [330]:

df.groupby('Server Name').count().reset_index()
Out[330]:
  Server Name  Missing Patch
0    Server 1              3
1    Server 2              4
2    Server 3              5
```

Comment: Ah ok - sorry I'm quite new to stackoverflow